# $count in mongodb under aggregation framkework

Tags: mongodb, count, aggregation-framework

I need to write a code that solves the following question:

> On genres, get the top actors who have participated in more genres.

I start from the following .json file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VKuhce2ofjLjYEoND_Fz2wqcYHAf6kkZ/view

So I created the *genres* collection:

```
 //unwind
    db.getCollection("actors").find({})
    fase1 = { $unwind: "$genres"}
    etapas = [fase1]
    db.Tarea.aggregate( etapas )

    //out
    fase1 = { $unwind: "$genres" }
    query2 = { "_id": 0 }
    fase2 = { $project: query2 }
    fase3 = { $out: "genres" }
    etapas = [ fase1, fase2, fase3 ]
    db.actors.aggregate( etapas )
```

Then I tried to aggregate them. And I would say that I practically have it, only that I need the count that appears in "numgeneros" to be the count of genres for each actor

```
db.genres.aggregate([
   {$match: { 
       "genres" : {$ne:"Undefined"},
       "cast" : {$ne:"Undefined"}
       }},

       {$group: {
            _id: "$cast",
            numgeneros: {$count: "$genres"},
            genres: { $addToSet: "$genres"}
       }},
       {$sort: {numgeneros:-1}},
    {$limit:10}
])
```

This is what I get:

[image]

And what I need is that, for example, the count of Harold Lloyd is equal to 4, which is the number of genres in which it appears instead of 236.

**Thanks to everyone beforehand!**

**@RLD Solution** works perfectly:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following query.

```
db.genres.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "genres": {
        $ne: "Undefined"
      },
      "cast": {
        $ne: "Undefined"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$cast",
      genreset: {
        $addToSet: "$genres"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      numgeneros: {
        $size: "$genreset"
      },
      genreset:1
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      numgeneros: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 10
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you. This code counts perfectly but does not show genres types.

Comment: @Adrian, can you run the query now? I have modified it as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

you can run the following aggregation on the movies collection and get what you need:

```java
db.movies.aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$cast"
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "actor": "$cast",
            "genres": "$genres",
            "_id": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$genres"
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "actor": "$actor",
            "genre": "$genres",
            "_id": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$actor",
            "genres": {
                "$addToSet": "$genre"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "actor": "$_id",
            "genreCount": {
                "$size": "$genres"
            },
            "genres": "$genres",
            "_id": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort": {
            "genreCount": - 1
        }
    },
    {
        "$limit": 10
    }
])
```

here's the c# program that generated the above:

```js
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class movie : Entity
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public int year { get; set; }
        public string[] cast { get; set; }
        public string[] genres { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test", "localhost");

            var res = DB.Queryable<movie>() // for official driver use: collection.AsQueryable()

                        .SelectMany(m => m.cast,
                                   (m, a) => new
                                   {
                                       actor = a,
                                       m.genres
                                   })

                        .SelectMany(x => x.genres,
                                   (x, g) => new
                                   {
                                       x.actor,
                                       genre = g
                                   })

                        .GroupBy(x => x.actor,
                                (a, x) => new
                                {
                                    actor = a,
                                    genres = x.Select(x => x.genre).Distinct()
                                })

                        .Select(x => new
                        {
                            x.actor,
                            genreCount = x.genres.Count(),
                            x.genres
                        })

                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.genreCount)

                        .Take(10)

                        .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you too. This code perfectly solves the issue.